# Gulp not refresh on changes to imported scss files

Tags: sass, gulp, jhipster, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

Gulp task in jhipster is not refreshing the main.css file when I change imported *.scss files, only if I change main.scss. The watch task in gulp shows me changes but nothing happens.

Gulpfile.js

```
// Generated on 2016-03-14 using generator-jhipster 2.27.2
/* jshint camelcase: false */
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
    usemin = require('gulp-usemin'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate'),
    ngConstant = require('gulp-ng-constant-fork'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    protractor = require('gulp-protractor').protractor,
    proxy = require('proxy-middleware'),
    es = require('event-stream'),
    flatten = require('gulp-flatten'),
    del = require('del'),
    url = require('url'),
    wiredep = require('wiredep').stream,
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    KarmaServer = require('karma').Server,
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    changed = require('gulp-changed'),
    cache = require('gulp-cached'),
    handleErrors = require('./gulp/handleErrors'),
    util = require('./gulp/utils');

var config = {
    app: 'src/main/webapp/',
    dist: 'src/main/webapp/dist/',
    test: 'src/test/javascript/',
    importPath: 'src/main/webapp/bower_components',
    scss: 'src/main/scss/',
    port: 9000,
    apiPort: 8080,
    liveReloadPort: 35729
};

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del([config.dist]);
});

gulp.task('test', ['wiredep:test', 'ngconstant:dev'], function (done) {
    //TODO LW UNCOMMENT WORKING ..
/*    new KarmaServer({
        configFile: __dirname + '/' + config.test + 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done).start();*/
});

gulp.task('protractor', function () {
    return gulp.src([config.test + 'e2e/*.js'])
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(protractor({
            configFile: config.test + 'protractor.conf.js'
        }));
});

gulp.task('copy', function () {
    return es.merge(  // copy i18n folders only if translation is enabled
        gulp.src(config.app + 'i18n/**')
            .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
            .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'i18n/'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'i18n/')),
        gulp.src(config.app + 'bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/*.*')
            .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
            .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'assets/fonts/'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'assets/fonts/')),
        gulp.src(config.app + 'assets/**/*.{woff,svg,ttf,eot}')
            .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
            .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'assets/fonts/'))
            .pipe(flatten())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'assets/fonts/')));
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'assets/images/**')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'assets/images'))
        .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'assets/images'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.scss + 'main.scss')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.app + 'assets/styles', {extension: '.css'}))
        .pipe(sass({includePaths: config.importPath}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'assets/styles'));
});

gulp.task('styles', ['sass'], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'assest/styles')
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('install', function (done) {
    runSequence('wiredep', 'ngconstant:dev', 'sass', done);
});

gulp.task('serve', function () {
    runSequence('install', function () {
        var baseUri = 'http://localhost:' + config.apiPort;
        // Routes to proxy to the backend. Routes ending with a / will setup
        // a redirect so that if accessed without a trailing slash, will
        // redirect. This is required for some endpoints for proxy-middleware
        // to correctly handle them.
        var proxyRoutes = [
            '/api',
            '/health',
            '/configprops',
            '/env',
            '/v2/api-docs',
            '/swagger-ui',
            '/configuration/security',
            '/configuration/ui',
            '/swagger-resources',
            '/metrics',
            '/websocket/tracker',
            '/dump'
        ];

        var requireTrailingSlash = proxyRoutes.filter(function (r) {
            return util.endsWith(r, '/');
        }).map(function (r) {
            // Strip trailing slash so we can use the route to match requests
            // with non trailing slash
            return r.substr(0, r.length - 1);
        });

        var proxies = [
            // Ensure trailing slash in routes that require it
            function (req, res, next) {
                requireTrailingSlash.forEach(function (route) {
                    if (url.parse(req.url).path === route) {
                        res.statusCode = 301;
                        res.setHeader('Location', route + '/');
                        res.end();
                    }
                });

                next();
            }
        ]
            .concat(
                // Build a list of proxies for routes: [route1_proxy, route2_proxy, ...]
                proxyRoutes.map(function (r) {
                    var options = url.parse(baseUri + r);
                    options.route = r;
                    options.preserveHost = true;
                    return proxy(options);
                }));

        browserSync({
            open: false,
            port: config.port,
            reloadDelay: 1000,
            server: {
                baseDir: config.app,
                middleware: proxies
            }
        });

        gulp.start('watch');
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep']);
    gulp.watch(['gulpfile.js', 'build.gradle'], ['ngconstant:dev']);
    gulp.watch(config.scss + '**/*.{scss,sass}', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'assets/images/**', ['images']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'scripts/**/*.js', ['jshint']);
    gulp.watch([config.app + '*.html', config.app + 'scripts/**', config.app + 'i18n/**']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('wiredep', ['wiredep:test', 'wiredep:app']);

gulp.task('wiredep:app', function () {
    var stream = gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(wiredep({
            exclude: [/angular-i18n/]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));

    return es.merge(stream, gulp.src(config.scss + '*.{scss,sass}')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(wiredep({
            exclude: [
                /angular-i18n/,  // localizations are loaded dynamically
                'bower_components/bootstrap/' // Exclude Bootstrap LESS as we use bootstrap-sass
            ],
            ignorePath: /\.\.\/webapp\/bower_components\// // remove ../webapp/bower_components/ from paths of injected sass files
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.scss)));
});

gulp.task('wiredep:test', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.test + 'karma.conf.js')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(wiredep({
            exclude: [/angular-i18n/, /angular-scenario/],
            ignorePath: /\.\.\/\.\.\//, // remove ../../ from paths of injected javascripts
            devDependencies: true,
            fileTypes: {
                js: {
                    block: /(([\s\t]*)\/\/\s*bower:*(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/\/\s*endbower)/gi,
                    detect: {
                        js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
                    },
                    replace: {
                        js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
                    }
                }
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.test));
});

gulp.task('build', function (cb) {
    runSequence('clean', 'copy', 'wiredep:app', 'ngconstant:prod', 'usemin', cb);
});

gulp.task('usemin', ['images', 'styles'], function () {
    return gulp.src([config.app + '**/*.html', '!' + config.app + '@(dist|bower_components)/**/*.html'])
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(usemin({
            css: [
                prefix,
                'concat',
                cssnano,
                rev
            ],
            html: [
                htmlmin.bind(htmlmin, {collapseWhitespace: true})
            ],
            js: [
                sourcemaps.init,
                ngAnnotate,
                'concat',
                uglify.bind(uglify, {mangle: false}),
                rev,
                sourcemaps.write.bind(sourcemaps.write, '.')
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:dev', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        dest: 'app.constants.js',
        name: 'adminApp',
        deps: false,
        noFile: true,
        interpolate: /\{%=(.+?)%\}/g,
        wrap: '/* jshint quotmark: false */\n"use strict";\n// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT THE GULP TASK NGCONSTANT SETTINGS INSTEAD WHICH GENERATES THIS FILE\n{%= __ngModule %}',
        constants: {
            BUILD_CONFIG: {
                ENV: 'dev',
                VERSION: util.parseVersion()

            }
        }
    })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'scripts/app/'));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:test', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        dest: 'app.constants.js',
        name: 'adminApp',
        deps: false,
        noFile: true,
        interpolate: /\{%=(.+?)%\}/g,
        wrap: '/* jshint quotmark: false */\n"use strict";\n// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT THE GULP TASK NGCONSTANT SETTINGS INSTEAD WHICH GENERATES THIS FILE\n{%= __ngModule %}',
        constants: {
            BUILD_CONFIG: {
                ENV: 'prod',
                VERSION: util.parseVersion()
            }
        }
    })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'scripts/app/'));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:prod', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        dest: 'app.constants.js',
        name: 'adminApp',
        deps: false,
        noFile: true,
        interpolate: /\{%=(.+?)%\}/g,
        wrap: '/* jshint quotmark: false */\n"use strict";\n// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT THE GULP TASK NGCONSTANT SETTINGS INSTEAD WHICH GENERATES THIS FILE\n{%= __ngModule %}',
        constants: {
            BUILD_CONFIG: {
                ENV: 'prod',
                VERSION: util.parseVersion()
            }
        }
    })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'scripts/app/'));
});

gulp.task('jshint', function () {
    //Custom reporter (in task to have new instance each time)
    var jsHintErrorReporter = require('./gulp/jsHintErrorReporter');

    return gulp.src(['gulpfile.js', config.app + 'scripts/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(cache('jshint'))
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
        .pipe(jsHintErrorReporter());
});


gulp.task('itest', ['protractor']);

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

main.scss

```
.main {
    max-height: 80%;
}

// include custom variables
@import "app/reset/bootstrap-variables.scss";
@import "app/common/media-queries.scss";
// include bootstrap default mixins
//@import "bootstrap/_mixins";
@import "bootstrap.scss";

// utils
@import "app/utils/utils-background.scss";
@import "app/utils/utils-variables.scss";

// reset (mixins and variables)
@import "app/reset/bootstrap-reset.scss";

// layout
@import "app/layout/layout.scss";
@import "app/layout/header.scss";
@import "app/layout/sidebar.scss";

// Common
@import "app/common/animate.scss";
@import "app/common/font.scss";
@import "app/common/loading-bar.scss";
@import "app/common/print.scss";
@import "app/common/settings.scss";

// Charts
@import "app/charts/charts.scss";
@import "app/charts/easypie.scss";

// forms
@import "app/forms/form-extras.scss";
@import "app/forms/form-imgcrop.scss";
@import "app/forms/form-input.scss";
@import "app/forms/form-switch.scss";
@import "app/forms/form-validation.scss";
@import "app/forms/form-wizard.scss";
@import "app/forms/uiselect.scss";
@import "app/forms/slider.scss";

// grid
@import "app/grid/grid-table.scss";
@import "app/grid/masonry-grid.scss";
@import "app/grid/row-extra.scss";

// icons
@import "app/icons/feather-icons.scss";

// maps
@import "app/maps/gmap.scss";
@import "app/maps/vector-map.scss";

// tables
@import "app/tables/table-ngtable.scss";
@import "app/tables/table-responsive.scss";
@import "app/tables/table-datatables.scss";

// ui
@import "app/ui/alerts.scss";
@import "app/ui/button-extra.scss";
@import "app/ui/button-switch.scss";
@import "app/ui/dropdown-extra.scss";
@import "app/ui/panels-extra.scss";
@import "app/ui/placeholder.scss";
@import "app/ui/points.scss";
@import "app/ui/progress-extra.scss";

// components
@import "app/components/datepicker.scss";
@import "app/components/nestable.scss";
@import "app/components/portlets.scss";
@import "app/components/ripple.scss";
@import "app/components/scrollable.scss";
@import "app/components/toaster.scss";
@import "app/components/typeahead.scss";
@import "app/components/layermorph.scss";

// extras
@import "app/extras/calendar.scss";
@import "app/extras/chat.scss";
@import "app/extras/mailbox.scss";
@import "app/extras/tasks.scss";
@import "app/extras/timeline-2.scss";
@import "app/extras/timeline.scss";

// utils
@import "app/utils/utils.scss";

.form-filter .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-width: 154px;
}

.form-filter button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm with the same problem the imports trigger the browser refresh but not generate the changes into main.css, only if I go to main.scss and click save

Answer (score 4):

I was with the same problem and right now I had discovered the problem is with "changed" plugin being used inside the sass tasks, just comment:

`.pipe(changed(config.app + 'assets/styles', {extension: '.css'}))`

In my version of jhipster is `.pipe(changed(config.cssDir, {extension: '.css'}))` )

That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch all your scss files

```
    gulp.watch('your path to your scss files here',['sass']);
```

Comment: Is already watching in this line:

`gulp.watch(config.scss + '**/*.{scss,sass}', ['styles']);`

'styles' task is calling sass task, the problem is with changed plugin